# Dedupe code on code library using Webpack 4

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

Currently I'm creating a component library using Webpack 4. Looking at the build results I find some shared component code are duplicated, here's an example of my case:

**Components**

```
- SampleComp
- SampleComp2
```

In this case, `SampleComp` are importing `SampleComp2` inside of it.

```
- SampleComp
-- SampleComp2

- SampleComp2
```

When I build it, `SampleComp2` are duplicated in `SampleComp` code which isn't ideal, so I look upon `optimization.splitChunks` documentations. Then I changed my config following several examples.

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    SampleComp: path.resolve(__dirname, './lib/components/SampleComp/index.tsx'),
    SampleComp2: path.resolve(__dirname, './lib/components/SampleComp2/index.tsx'),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    globalObject: "typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : this",
  },
  mode: 'production',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          babelrc: false,
          ...babelConfig,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        commons: {
          chunks: 'initial',
          minChunks: 2,
          maxInitialRequests: 5,
          minSize: 0
        },
      }
    }
  },
};
```

And when I build it, it creates a common chunk shared between the two components:

[image]

But when I tried to try the component locally by linking the library to some CRA projects, I'm always getting `TypeError: jsonpArray.push is undefined`.

Am I doing it wrong? Or I miss a step here? Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain how you're doing this? → "But when I tried to try the component locally by linking the library to some CRA projects"

Comment: @Atav32 basically my I just use `yarn link` on my library directory, then I use the linked library to my local CRA projects using `yarn link my-library` then I start using the component inside build folder.

Comment: Are you linking the component's src directory or the output dir from Webpack?

Comment: Which build folder are you referring to? → "I start using the component inside build folder."

Comment: @Atav32 Yes, I'm linking to the output dir from webpack of my library, in this case the output folder named `build`.

Comment: What happens if you add a `library` field to the Webpack `output` object? https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#expose-the-library